# Want to lazy load panel data in jsf application

Tags: jsf, lazy-loading, accordionpane

I have numerous AccordionPanel in my jsf page.

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" id="HomeAddress">
```

so everytime we add new accordion panel and load the page, it is taking long time to load all the panel.So I want to lazy load the panels. At first load five panel and once we scroll to the end it will load rest of the panels. Something like happening in all e-commerce site (Flipkart, Amazon etc..)

Answer (score 0):

An accordionPanel is one componenent and like most complex PF components, it does not allow updating one of it's children or dynamicaly adding one (tabs in this case). And dynamicaly loading is an even different thing. You can achieve this by adding an

```
<p:outputPanel deferred="true" deferredMode="visible">...

</p:outputPanel>
```

inside each tab and put the content in there. But adding a tab to the accordionpanel will still reload all tabs, lazy, ok, but still reload them when accessed